# Friend member function compiles in GCC but not in Clang or MSVC

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, friend-function

I have been working with the following program that compiles with GCC, but is rejected by both Clang and MSVC.

[Godbolt Demo link](https://godbolt.org/z/Mz8cq3G5n)

```cpp
template <typename>
class X {
   
    void f(){}
};
class Y
{
    friend void X<int>::f();  
};

int main()
{
    X<int> t;
    t.f();
    Y b;
}
```

As you can see the above program works with GCC, but Clang says:

```
<source>:9:25: error: friend function 'f' is a private member of 'X<int>'
    friend void X<int>::f();  
                ~~~~~~~~^
<source>:9:25: note: implicitly declared private here
<source>:15:7: error: 'f' is a private member of 'X<int>'
    t.f();
      ^
<source>:9:25: note: implicitly declared private here
    friend void X<int>::f();  
                        ^
2 errors generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

I want to know what the correct behavior of the program is; which compiler is correct according to the standard? I am using C++20.

Comment: Seems to me to be a gcc regression in 13.1. 12.4 rejects it.

Comment: If I look away from the friend stuff, `t.f()` should not succeed due to f being private (stuff happening in class Y should not be able to change that). Another vote for gcc bug.

Answer (score 4):

The program is **ill-formed** because the qualified-name `X<int>::f` is not accessible inside the class `Y` that contains the friend declaration. This can be seen from [class.friend](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.friend#9):

> **A name nominated by a friend declaration shall be accessible in the scope of the class containing the friend declaration.**
> The meaning of the friend declaration is the same whether the friend declaration appears in the private, protected, or public ([class.mem]) portion of the class member-specification.

(emphasis mine)

And since the name `X<int>::f` nominated by the friend declaration `friend void X<int>::f();` is not accessible inside the containing class `Y`, the program is ill-formed and **GCC is wrong in accepting the program**.

---

Here is the corresponding GCC bug:

[GCC accepts invalid inaccessible friend declaration of member function](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=109649)